# LMFIT vs. LSMR am I getting different fits due to machine precision?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

I've been playing around with using LMFIT vs. LMSR for fitting of linear systems. The coefficients of this system are in fact derived from global parameters that are also being fit (i.e. I have a nested solver). But the solutions I get using these different solvers are different, despite similar setups.

Here is my MVE

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsmr
from lmfit import minimize,Parameters

data_1=[[117.417, 117.423, 117.438, 117.501], [124.16, 124.231, 124.089, 124.1], [115.632, 115.645, 115.828, 115.947], [118.314, 118.317, 118.287, 118.228], [108.407, 108.419, 108.396, 108.564], [116.636, 116.648, 116.684, 116.729], [122.874, 122.905, 122.851, 122.894], [114.958, 115.059, 115.044, 115.341], [110.322, 110.258, 110.177, 110.216], [129.049, 129.13, 129.139, 129.165], [122.679, 122.699, 122.685, 122.668], [120.965, 120.965, 120.946, 120.915], [120.709, 120.73, 120.723, 120.686], [115.351, 115.362, 115.389, 115.345], [118.593, 118.687, 118.738, 118.71], [114.48, 114.402, 114.601, 114.502], [118.714, 118.768, 118.869, 119.148], [116.406, 116.322, 116.288, 116.143], [122.459, 122.475, 122.424, 122.411], [122.001, 121.961, 121.955, 121.965]]
data_2=[[9.05, 9.044, 9.057, 9.079], [9.178, 9.167, 9.16, 9.176], [7.888, 7.893, 7.911, 7.895], [7.198, 7.202, 7.197, 7.213], [7.983, 7.976, 7.979, 8.02], [8.215, 8.218, 8.223, 8.218], [8.099, 8.114, 8.109, 8.13], [8.781, 8.769, 8.778, 8.778], [9.605, 9.612, 9.59, 9.589], [8.985, 8.997, 8.998, 8.986], [9.361, 9.364, 9.368, 9.39], [8.123, 8.123, 8.106, 8.108], [9.192, 9.194, 9.201, 9.168], [8.78, 8.784, 8.798, 8.804], [8.47, 8.473, 8.482, 8.483], [8.567, 8.563, 8.552, 8.536], [8.022, 8.023, 8.04, 8.04], [10.063, 10.052, 10.026, 10.01], [7.745, 7.738, 7.74, 7.709], [8.741, 8.73, 8.739, 8.75]]

def chemical_shift_model(new_paramters,populations,experimental_shifts):
    return (populations@new_paramters)-experimental_shifts

def fit_residues(populations,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag):
    local_chi2_list=[]
    local_chi2=0
    for experimental_shifts_n,experimental_shifts_h in zip(data_1,data_2):
        experimental_shifts_n=(np.array([experimental_shifts_n])/10)*800
        experimental_shifts_h=(np.array([experimental_shifts_h]))*800
        new_paramters_n=Parameters()
        new_paramters_n.add('free',value=110)
        new_paramters_n.add('open',value=110)
        new_paramters_n.add('closed',value=110)
        new_paramters_h=Parameters()
        new_paramters_h.add('free',value=7)
        new_paramters_h.add('open',value=7)
        new_paramters_h.add('closed',value=7)
        if lm_fit_flag is True:
            solution_n=minimize(chemical_shift_model,new_paramters_n,args=(populations,experimental_shifts_n))
            solution_h=minimize(chemical_shift_model,new_paramters_h,args=(populations,experimental_shifts_h))
            local_chi2_list.append(solution_n.residual)
            local_chi2_list.append(solution_h.residual)
            local_chi2+=(solution_n.chisqr+solution_h.chisqr)
        else:
            least_squared_fit_n=lsmr(populations,experimental_shifts_n,maxiter=10)
            least_squared_fit_h=lsmr(populations,experimental_shifts_h,maxiter=10)
            local_chi2_list.append(populations@least_squared_fit_n[0]-experimental_shifts_n)
            local_chi2_list.append(populations@least_squared_fit_h[0]-experimental_shifts_h)
            local_chi2+=((least_squared_fit_n[3])**2+least_squared_fit_h[3]**2) 
    if scipy_flag is True:
        return local_chi2
    return (np.array(local_chi2_list)).flatten()

def get_populations(initial,io,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag):
    if scipy_flag is True:
        k,k1,x,y=float(initial[0]),float(initial[1]),initial[2],initial[3]
    else:   
        k,k1,x,y=float(initial['kvar'].value),float(initial['k1var'].value),float(initial['xvar'].value),float(initial['yvar'].value)
    k_array=np.array([k,k*x,k*y,k*x*y])
    k1_array=np.array([k1,k1*x,k1*y,k1*x*y])
    partial_free_concentration=(np.sqrt((k_array*k1_array)**2+(8*io*k_array*k1_array)+(8*io*k_array*k1_array**2))-(k_array*k1_array))/(4*(1+k1_array))
    partial_closed_concentration=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1_array))/(4*(1+k1_array)**2))-(partial_free_concentration/(1+k1_array))
    partial_open_concentration=k1_array*partial_closed_concentration
    populations=(np.stack((partial_free_concentration,partial_open_concentration,partial_closed_concentration),axis=1)/io)
    return fit_residues(populations,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag) 
io=270_000
```

So I am doing 2 fits here. One is for parameters k,k1,x,y which are used to calculate the coefficients for the next system to solve with data coming from data_1,data_2. The reason for the flags are because scipy and lmfit are using different methods and require different formats for inputs and outputs (i.e. scipy uses list input with scalar output, lmfit uses dict input with  array of residuals output). So I have a setup here that tests 4 different scenarios using the flags:

1. Scipy for global (non linear), scipy/LSMR for local (linear)
2. Scipy for global (non linear), LMFIT for local (linear)
3. LMFIT for global (non linear), scipy/LSMR for local (linear)
4. LMFIT for both

The problem is the output, so say we test using Scipy/LSMR and compare this to Scipy/LMFIT

```
#scenario 1
scipy_flag=True
lm_fit_flag=False
print(so.minimize(get_populations,args=(io,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag),bounds=((0,np.inf),)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'maxiter':1000},x0=np.array([500,2e-2,7,30])))
#scenario 2
scipy_flag=True
lm_fit_flag=True
print(so.minimize(get_populations,args=(io,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag),bounds=((0,np.inf),)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'maxiter':1000},x0=np.array([500,2e-2,7,30])))
```

The respective solutions

```
#scenario 1
message: Optimization terminated successfully.
       success: True
        status: 0
           fun: 481.9183017741435
             x: [ 1.127e+03  4.283e-07  1.448e+02  6.792e+02]
           nit: 279
          nfev: 538
#scenario 2
message: Optimization terminated successfully.
       success: True
        status: 0
           fun: 482.14321287433705
             x: [ 7.043e+02  1.588e-11  9.453e+00  4.316e+01]
           nit: 254
          nfev: 521
```

We can see both found solutions, but both are completely different from each other. Now is this a setup issue, or is this a minimizer issue? If I look at just plugging in value (so no minimization)

```
#scenario 1
scipy_flag=True
lm_fit_flag=False
print(get_populations([500,0.02,7,30],io,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag))
#scenario 2
scipy_flag=True
lm_fit_flag=True
print(get_populations([500,0.02,7,30],io,scipy_flag,lm_fit_flag))
```

The solutions for the sum of residuals are almost identical

```
#scenario 1
508.04726728449936
#scenario 2
508.04726728447883
```

So we can see here I have set things up correctly, and both LMFIT and LMSR are fitting the same way, giving almost exact answers to the 1e-10 correction (I presume this is approaching machine precesion).

Now if we truncate data_1 and data_2, so we only use the first half of each dataset, we can see the solutions do end up converging:

```
data_1=[[117.417, 117.423, 117.438, 117.501], [124.16, 124.231, 124.089, 124.1], [115.632, 115.645, 115.828, 115.947], [118.314, 118.317, 118.287, 118.228], [108.407, 108.419, 108.396, 108.564], [116.636, 116.648, 116.684, 116.729], [122.874, 122.905, 122.851, 122.894], [114.958, 115.059, 115.044, 115.341], [110.322, 110.258, 110.177, 110.216], [129.049, 129.13, 129.139, 129.165]]
data_2=[[9.05, 9.044, 9.057, 9.079], [9.178, 9.167, 9.16, 9.176], [7.888, 7.893, 7.911, 7.895], [7.198, 7.202, 7.197, 7.213], [7.983, 7.976, 7.979, 8.02], [8.215, 8.218, 8.223, 8.218], [8.099, 8.114, 8.109, 8.13], [8.781, 8.769, 8.778, 8.778], [9.605, 9.612, 9.59, 9.589], [8.985, 8.997, 8.998, 8.986]]
```

Using the same 2 scenarios with the same conditions as above but now using this shortened dataset, we can get identical solutions:

```
#scenario 1
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
       success: True
        status: 0
           fun: 329.3893192091266
             x: [ 4.898e+02  2.367e-02  4.986e+00  3.908e+01]
           nit: 121
          nfev: 241
#scenario 2
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
       success: True
        status: 0
           fun: 329.3893192092007
             x: [ 4.898e+02  2.367e-02  4.986e+00  3.908e+01]
           nit: 110
          nfev: 225
```

So **assuming** my setup is correct, the code is correct, I have setup the solvers properly, the solution simply diverges once I add more data.

Is this occurring because my chi2 landscape is so poorly defined/flat, that the true "minima" is within machine precision error resulting in me getting different answers when trying to fit using different solvers?

Basically I'm just trying to ensure it's my data that is garbage, not my code or how I've set everything up.

I should note I haven't shown any code for when you use LMFIT for the global parameters (scenario 3 and 4), but I have the same issue there.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot follow your code - it's basically unreadable.  You're doing some weird nesting of solvers that seems designed to complicate things.  Is it surprising that lmfit.minimize and scipy.optimize.lsmr might sometimes give different results?   Like, are you expecting them always to give identical results?    Are the results, in fact, very different -- and how do you know that?   Definitely, clean up the code, simplify the problem, and compare intermediate results.

Comment: 1. I don't quite know how else to simplify this? It's 50 lines of code, there are global parameters that are minimized (k,k1,x,y) which generate the coefficients for the linear system of local parameters being minimized (chemical shift model). The 2 are dependent on one another (I don't know how to do this outside of nested solvers). 2. They do give identical results. The results start to diverge as more data is added. I am concerned if the code is setup properly which is why I am getting divergence, or if the data just sucks and the code is fine. I have posted the solutions for both scenarios

Comment: sorry, but I just cannot follow or really even read your code. Shorter variable names, some spaces, and less nesting might help with readability, but I'm not sure it would help with comprehension.  I don't see how your Parameters "free", "open", and "closed" are even used.

Comment: they are stored into the parameters dict that is used by LMFIT. That isn't a formatting issue, it's the syntax used by LMFIT.